# JBoss server.log parsing in stream

Tags: logging, jboss, tail

There is a need to parse server log, to gather all Errors and Warnings and detect when Broken Pipe error occurs among others

The following command does this perfectly when I'm talking about post processing

```
cat server.log |grep 'ERROR\|WARN' -A1 |grep -v 'Timed out waiting for last message'|grep -v -- "^--$" |grep -v 'DEBUG'|sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

and gives result like:

> 2021-03-16 15:26:57,128 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread] Worker thread initialization failure java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

> 2021-03-16 15:26:57,129 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread] Worker thread initialization failure java.io.IOException: Connection reset

but when i'm trying to make same using tail

```
tail -f server.log |grep 'ERROR\|WARN' -A1 |grep -v 'Timed out waiting for last message'|grep -v -- '^--$' |grep -v 'DEBUG'|sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

nothing works as expected.

The problem that I need in one line date time and error type and exception text

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: Version: 4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=200707131606)
Version Name: Trinity
Built on: July 13 2007